# can we create create statement inside cursor loop in oracle

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Can we do CTAS inside a cursor in oracle 
I am trying below code 
declare 
l_email_string varchar2(100);
cursor c1 is 
select * from EMAIL_OBS where rownum < 2;

begin

for rec in C1 
loop

```
    create table ABC_TEST 
    (
    row_id  , 
    email_string 
    )
    as
    select 
    rowid , 
    jasbk
    from EMAIL_OBS ;
```

end loop ; 
end  ;
/

but it is showing error while if I remove CTAS then it is working fine 
Please suggest

Thanks ,
Abhimpi

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform DDL in PL/SQL like this (CTAS is DDL). You will need to use Dynamic SQL. Look up 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' for examples.